# JETTY_LOGS is being appended to JETTY_HOME

Tags: java, centos, jetty

I'm trying to run Jetty on CentOS and am having problems as I am getting unexpected results when I try to set the full path for JETTY_LOGS.  The system tries to take that path and append it to the path I specified in the JETTY_HOME variable.

```
JETTY_HOME=/usr/local/jetty/jetty-9.1.4
JETTY_USER=jetty
JETTY_PORT=8085
JETTY_HOST=0.0.0.0
JETTY_LOGS=/usr/local/jetty/jetty-9.1.4/logs
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

The error I get is:

```
Starting Jetty: java.io.IOException: Cannot write start.log to directory
/usr/local/jetty/jetty-9.1.4/usr/local/jetty/jetty-9.1.4/logs [directory doesn't exist or is read-only]
java.io.IOException: Cannot write start.log to directory /usr/local/jetty/jetty-9.1.4/usr/local/jetty/jetty-9.1.4/logs [directory doesn't exist or is read-only]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.StartLog.initLogFile(StartLog.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.StartLog.initialize(StartLog.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:102)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that JETTY_LOG directory is relative to JETTY_HOME.

Could you try to set:

```
 JETTY_LOGS=/logs
```

or alternatively

```
 JETTY_HOME=/usr/local/jetty/jetty-9.1.4/
 JETTY_LOGS=logs
```

Comment: If I specify JETTY_LOGS=logs it works to some degree, but will also attempt to use ~/logs to log to. JETTY_LOGS=/logs does the same thing.

Comment: After recreating my user using the  -r -m options, it is working with just supplying JETTY_LOGS=logs

Comment: By the way I found this site super usefull to help install jetty.  [link](http://www.copper-arrow.com/blog/jetty-web-server-centos-6)

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong, this is new behavior in jetty 9.1.4:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432192

Workaround is to set the `JETTY_LOGS` env var relative to your jetty base dir (like the `logs` dir that comes in the standard jetty tarball):

```
JETTY_LOGS=logs
```

Which will resolve to `/usr/local/jetty/jetty-9.1.4/logs` in your case (the jetty base dir defaults to the jetty home dir).

If you want the logs written somewhere outside of your jetty base dir, the best way is to use the above `JETTY_LOGS=logs` env setting, and just symlink the dir elsewhere; like this to create and link to the common `/var/log/jetty` dir:

```
# mv /usr/local/jetty/jetty-9.1.4/logs /var/log/jetty
# ln -s /var/log/jetty /usr/local/jetty/jetty-9.1.4/logs
```

Whatever you do, also make sure that the user as which you run jetty has write access to the logs dir; if you use the `jetty` user in the `jetty` group, make it the owner of your logs dir:

```
# chown -R jetty:jetty /var/log/jetty
```